# Can I change the Windows 10 Automatic accent colour palette?

Tags: windows-10, colors, themes

Recent updates to Windows 10 brought back Windows 8's feature where the window/UI color was derived from the current wallpaper: "Automatically pick an accent colour from my background":

[image: alt]

However Windows does not pick an *actual* colour from the wallpaper, instead it picks from its internal palette of about 8 colours, some of which are nice, but others are rather unattractive, such as the "vomit brown" you can see in my screenshot example, even though my current wallpaper is blue and amber.

Is there a way to set the colours in that palette? Are they stored in the registry somewhere or as an embedded resource somewhere else? I couldn't see anything relevant in `aero.msstyles` unfortunately.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? It's driving me insane. Vomit Brown? How about that Vomit Green??

Answer (score 0):

This was posted in this forum by someone, who made a little batch file which brings back the Windows 7 full colour and background choice options.  Just put this single line into Notepad and save it as a .bat file:

control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper

Comment: this only open the desktop control site to change the wallpaper but no color

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 Creators Update, which will be released in 2017, will [include an option to define your own accent color](http://winaero.com/blog/finally-custom-accent-colors-are-coming-to-windows-10/).

[image]

Comment: But would Windows pick those custom colours for the "Automatically pick a colour..." option? Otherwise this is of no help for my problem.

Comment: I don't use this automatic color thing. I want full control. Wait when this update is released if it includes what you want.

Comment: I want automatic colours, but I don't want it to pick ugly colours.